# Valor nulo en llamada a base de datos (SQLite)

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

Estoy haciendo una app que requiere de base de datos en donde al consultar / buscar un numero en la primer columna de la base de datos, te regresa el dato que se encuentra en la segunda columna que corresponde a ese dato.
El **problema** es que cuando ingreso el numero **me regresa un valor null**, no se que es lo que me esta fallando.

Este es el código de la conexión a la base de datos y demás

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "";

private static String DB_NAME = "Prueba.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

public DB(Context context, String Prueba, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
    super(context, DB_NAME, factory, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH= myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
}


public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //Si la base de datos ya existe -> no hagas nada
    }else{

        //Al llamar este metodo y cuando este la base de datos vacia se creara por defecto una en el system path
        //de mi propia aplicacion entonces se podra sobreescribir esa base de datos con la nuestra.
        this.getWritableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }

    }

}


/**
 * Si la base de datos ya existe evitar que se vuelva a copiar el archivo cada ves que se abre la aplicacion.
 * @return true si ya existe, false si no.
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    //  this.getReadableDatabase();

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {


    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}


/**
 * Copia tu base de datos desde tu folder de assets (local) para que solo se cree la base de datos vacia
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH ;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Cierra los streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws java.sql.SQLException {

    //Abre la base de datos
    String myPath = DB_PATH ;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

}

public String[] buscar_reg(String buscar){
    String[] Orden = new String[3];
    //SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM Orden WHERE no_orden ='" + buscar +"'";
    Cursor registros = database.rawQuery(q, null);
    if (registros.moveToFirst()){
        for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
            Orden[i]=registros.getString(i);
        }
        Orden[2]="Encontrado";
    }else {
        Orden[2]="No se encontro la orden #"+buscar;
    }
    database.close();
    return Orden;
}

}
```

Y a continuación esta el código del MainActivity que es donde se encuentra el "buscador", en el cual ingresas el numero y este lo manda a la activity de la conexión a la base de datos, al final del código anterior puede verse donde hace la operación para buscar el numero en la columna correspondiente.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText E_buscar;
TextView no_orden, estado;
Button B_buscar, B_Lista;
DB db ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    no_orden = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.no_orden);
    estado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.estado);

    E_buscar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.E_buscar);

    B_buscar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B_buscar);
    B_Lista = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B_Lista);
    db= new DB(this, "Orden", null, 1);

    fetchData();

    B_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DB db = new DB(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
            String buscar = E_buscar.getText().toString();
            String[] Orden;
            Orden = db.buscar_reg(buscar);
            no_orden.setText("\nOrden #" + Orden[0] + "\n");
            estado.setText(Orden[1] + "\n");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Orden[2],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public void fetchData() {
    db = new DB(this,"Orden", null, 1);
    try {

        db.createDataBase();
        db.openDataBase();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Gracias espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: estado.setText(Orden[1] + "\n"); es el valor que obtienes como null?  Cual es la estructura de tu tabla y que tipo de dato tienen los primeros 3 campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No has implementado los métodos onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) y onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) de tu clase DB.

El primero de estos métodos se llama cuando la base de datos se crea por primera vez. Es en este método donde tienes que crear las tablas de la base de datos.

Deberías por tanto implementar este método. Algo parecido a esto

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DB_NAME + " (" + <nombre de columna> + <tipo de dato> + <,> ... + " )";
}
```

De todos modos, deberías repasar bien la documentación. Te dejo un enlace donde puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo implementar esta clase.
[Cómo guardar datos en bases de datos SQL](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=es-419)

Espero que te sirva de algo